# return special price to blank value

Tags: product, template, simple-product, sku, special-price

I am trying to return the special price that some products have to the value that they had by default "blank value" or eliminating the value that these have, I want to do it loading template since there are many, what fields should I use apart from the sku field? to carry out this change.

[image]

[image]

[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set empty values for `special_price`, that should remove the Special Price from the products.
If that doesnt work, try setting the value to `__EMPTY__VALUE__` for `special_price`

Comment: Thank you very much Ahmad. Your answer has been satisfactory and with this indicated value I have been able to perform the updates using CSV templates.